# Meaning of "T-vector of time series values"?

Tags: time-series, terminology, hierarchical-bayesian, notation

I am currently studying a paper on Hierarchical Bayesian space-time models. In that, we have denoted $Y(s,t)$ to be the process of interest ate location $s$ and time $t$ in a gridded space-time. $Y(s, )$ is denoted as to be the T-vector of time series values at site $s$ where $T$ is the total number of time points.

Can someone explain to me what does this statement means? -  **T-vector of time series values**.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a direct quote when the phrase appears and it's source?

Comment: http://www.stat.missouri.edu/~wikle/WikleBerlinerCressie1998.pdf - This is the link of the paper to which I am referring. In this see section 2 "Notation" 3rd paragrapgh.

Comment: Depending on the modelling strategy, it may be helpful to arrange the process in different ways. To that end, let $Y(s, )$ be the T-vector of time series values at site s. - this is the direct quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper you quote says

> Suppose $Y(s,t)$ denotes  the  value  of  the  process  of  interest 
>   at  location $s$ and  time $t$ ... there are $S$ sites and $T$ time
>   points, and hence the number of grid points is $S \times T$ ...
>   Depending  on  the  modelling  strategy,  it  may  be  helpful  to 
>   `arrange'  the  process  in different ways. To that end, let
>   $\boldsymbol{Y}(s,)$ be the $T$-vector of time series values at site
>   $s$. Let $\boldsymbol{Y}(,t)$ be the matrix of spatially gridded
>   values of the process at time $t$. Let
>   $\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{Y}}_t$ denote a vectorization of the
>   matrix $\boldsymbol{Y}(,t)$.

So $\boldsymbol{Y}$ is a $S \times T$ matrix where authors use $Y(s,t)$ as $\boldsymbol{Y}_{s,t}$ i.e. value at $s$-th row and $t$-th column of  $\boldsymbol{Y}$. By $Y(,t)$ they mean vector $\boldsymbol{Y}_{\cdot,t}$, i.e. vector of all values of $s$ at column fixed to $t$ -- they say "take the whole $t$-th column". So by $T$- or $S$-vector they mean "vector of all $t$'s" or of all $s$'s for some fixed value of $s$ or $t$.

Comment: - I have another query. In the same paper, $Z$ is denoted to be the observational data. What's the difference between $Z$ and $Y$. Is $Y$ the prior knowledge? Thanks in advance!